# How to make model motionless?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a model. And when I drag this model with the mouse or mouse wheel, it shifts. How to make the model not move.

This is model before dragging. the model is highlighted

[image: This is model before dragging. the model is highlighted]

This is the model after dragging it

[image: This is the model after dragging it]

Comment: You should add a minimal reproducible example to your questions. With images no one knows which view is used to render your model. The assumption is that it is based on a Flickable hence the "motion". So it is either a GridView, ListView or TableView. Nevertheless if you expect a proper answer you should write a proper question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this recent [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74863891/turning-off-the-bouncing-animation-for-qml-gridview-elements).

> GridView is a Flickable and Flickable was made for mobile use. You
> need to set the property boundsBehavior to Flickable.StopAtBounds. The
> default is Flickable.DragAndOvershootBounds. Have a look at the
> Flickable documentation.
>
> This fixes the overshoot behavior, but if enough items are in your
> GridView it can still be dragged/flicked by the user. To deactivate
> that you need to set interactive to false. If you do so you need to
> make sure that your users can still scroll the GridView to reach all
> the items that are potentially out of view. Probably you need to
> decorate the Flickable/GridView with a ScrollView.

TL;DR Set the `interactive` property to `false` on your `Flickable`/`GridView`/`ListView` that is showing your model data.

Comment: The question is next to impossible to answer but you managed to supply something!